When do you lose control of the ball in American football?
As I was watching the LSU/UCLA game on 2024-09-21, the UCLA running back had the ball stripped and it was ruled a fumble.  The instant slow-motion replay showed the LSU defender starting to rip the ball from the UCLA running back just before the running back's knee appeared to graze the ground.  I did not think that it was undisputable video evidence and thought the play would stand.  The play was overturned.  It made me realize that I really don't understand when a player "loses control" of the football. Do you have control of the ball if it is in the process of being stripped from your hands?  At what point has the player "lost control"?

the officials likely determined that the ball was coming loose before the running back’s knee touched the ground, which led to the ruling of a fumble. Instant replay is used to provide clear and indisputable evidence, but sometimes the interpretation can be subjective.
